# React.js setState not getting update wiith onclick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, use-state

This is my sample code, it's very basic i just want to console fname once submit is clicked.
When i pressed first time i get an empty line but when pressed second time the button i get some empty value. I am attaching the screenshot for the console.

I dont want to change my code to a class and use some method to get the value in console.

[screenshot for console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Dxi.png)

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

export const anyComponent = () => {
const [fname, setFname] = useState('')

const submit = (event) =>{
    setFname({fname: [event.target.value] })
    console.log(fname)
}
return(
<div>
    <input name="fname"  type="text" placeholder="Enter your First Name" />
    <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>

</div>

)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MDN Docs:

> The [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched.

In your case, event.target would point to the button and not input.

What you need is a reference to the input, you can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook for it like this

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default anyComponent = () => {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const [fname, setFname] = useState("");

  const submit = event => {
    setFname({ fname: [inputEl.current.value] });
  };

  console.log(fname);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name="fname"
        ref={inputEl}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your First Name"
      />
      <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also, setState is asynchronous, that's why you wouldn't see the result in the console just after calling `setFname`. However you'd see the updated `fName` in console on the next render, that's why I've moved it out of the `submit`.

**Without useRef**

Alternatively, you can add `onChange` handler on input and update the state `fname` from there

```js
function App(){
  const [fname, setFname] = useState("");

  const submit = () => {
    console.log(fname);
  };

  const handleChange = ev => {
   setFname({ fname: [ev.target.value] });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name="fname"
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your First Name"
      />
      <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: what will happen if instead of onClick i am using onChange in the input fname?
Will it be able to refer my input field?
without using useRef there is a way?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, you can do that. I've updated the answer to show how it can be done.

Comment: I got my answer, even without using useRef if i move my console.log outside of the submit. But thanks for this useRef i was not aware about it.

Answer (score -1):

Your console log should be outside submit method. Or log `event.target.value` instead fname.